# Is there a shortcut to quickly add an html class tag in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I learned a lot of shortcuts in Visual Studio Code, some natives and some others from extensions, but I didn't succeed to find any "addClass" extension for HTML. I know we can add one with Emmet on a div creation, but is there a way to quickly add a class tag if the div is already written?

Comment: inside the tag type `class` and at some point press `TAB`

Comment: @rioV8 Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't work if I click on the text of a <h1> for example. To be more precise, I would like to click on a div, place the cursor anywhere, and then do a little shortcut that automatically adds a new class tag and places the cursor inside the quotes. If this extension doesn't exist yet, I hope it's feasible.

Comment: place the cursor before the `>` and type ` class` (note the space)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of 2 extensions: [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command) and [Select By](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.select-by)

Define this keybinding: (choose your own keycombo)

```
{
  "key": "alt+x", // any other key combo
  "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
  "args": {
    "sequence": [
      { "command": "moveby.regex",
        "args": { "regex": ">", "properties": ["next", "start"]}},
      { "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
        "args": { "snippet": " class=\"$1\"$0" } }
    ]
  }
}
```

Place the cursor in the start tag (**not** before the `>`) and press key combo.

I will add an option to the `moveby.regex` command to allow the cursor at the right location so you can place the cursor also before the `>`.

**Edit**

with [Select By](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.select-by) v1.5.0 you can place the cursor anywhere in the start tag.

Modify the keybinding to (`checkCurrent` property)

```
{
  "key": "alt+x", // any other key combo
  "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
  "args": {
    "sequence": [
      { "command": "moveby.regex",
        "args": { "regex": ">", "properties": ["next", "start"]},
                  "checkCurrent": true },
      { "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
        "args": { "snippet": " class=\"$1\"$0" } }
    ]
  }
}
```

It also works with **Multi Cursor**.

Comment: @Jeireme now possible anywhere in the start tag

Answer (score 1):

if you want to add a class within a div tag or any element within Visual Studio Code, you can simply type "div.className", when you press enter the div tag will appear with a class which corresponds to the div tag. The "." feature works on any element of HTML

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes I already know about the Emmet shortcuts, but if I've already written the div earlier and that I only want to add a new class in it? I know I can type "class=className" manually, but I wonder if there is a way to do it even faster.

Comment: Hi, you can type class="firstClassName, secondClassName" and in the CSS you will be able to target the second class, also you can type "div.firstClassName,secondClassName" and once you click enter the div tag will have 2 classes which can be used in the CSS of the website. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

I reworked an extension that I wrote [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform) to simply do what you want (and a lot more).

In your `keybindings.json`:

```
{
  "key": "alt+r",
  "command": "findInCurrentFile",
  "args": {
    "find": ">",
    "replace": " class=\"@\">",
    "restrictFind": "once",
    "cursorMoveSelect": "@"
  }
}
```

[image: cursorMove demo]

This command will search for a `>` character, replace it with `" class=\"@\">"` and then move the cursor to and select the `@` character (which was added in the replace just to have an easy place to select).

The `cursorMoveSelect` value can be any text, not just a single character.

As you can see in the demo, you only need to place the cursor somewhere before the character you are searching for.

The replace field can take case modifiers, like `\U` and regex capture groups.

The find can be restricted to the first occurrence, all occurrences on a line, in selection(s) or the entire document.

The extension can also do searches across files with all the usual vscode options.

---

One benefit to the extension over simply doing a find/replace yourself is that these find/replacements can be stored for later use in the settings or simply in a keybinding.

Comment: Thank you! It's not working exactly the way I wanted, but it's still faster! @Mark

Comment: I added a couple of options to the extension so it is now more powerful and easily does what you want by itself.